# Golang serving html files

Tags: html, go, gorilla

I have some html files in folder /html (for example main.html,page1.html, page2.html,etc ). And I serve it, using next Go code

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(htmlDir))))
```

So if I open address http://127.0.0.1/page1.html, then page1.html will be shown( it is what I need).
But I also want to bind address http://127.0.0.1/ to main.html. How can I do it?

I can rename main.html to index.html, but I think it is not true way.

Answer (score 2):

You could additionally add a `HandlerFunc` to handle that:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(htmlDir))))
```

In the homeHandler you serve the file you want to serve:

```
func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, fmt.Sprintf("./%s/index.htm", htmlDir))
}
```

There might be other options...

Comment: Yes, I can. But it seems to be not simple way. I thought that can be one-two line way to do such simple thing.